# how to use httpclient in Rho-Mobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I am new to Rho-Mobile, and I want to know whether or not I can use http-client and how?

I googled the APIs for Rho-Mobile but unfortunately, I could not find any useful Info.

Answer (score 0):

The Rhomobile have an AsynchHttp API. The Rhomobile Docs have a few examples of how to use it [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/connect-to-web-services). Alternative, you can use the Ruby  *net/http* library. It is explained [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#ruby-extensions), how to use *net/http* as an extension to your Rhodes Application.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to extend Rhodes to use most Ruby libraries: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions

But of course there are built in solutions as mentioned: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/connect-to-web-services

Answer (score 0):

```
Rho::AsyncHttp.get(
  :url => "http://www.yourSite.com",
  :headers => {"Cookie" => cookie},
  :callback => (url_for :action => :httpget_callback)
)
```